# Posterior distribution from normal prior

Tags: probability, distributions, bayesian, conditional-probability

I was trying to compute the posterior distribution of $X|Y = y$ but I don't know what to do next. The problem is like this:

$X \sim N(10,1) $ and $Y|X = x\sim N(x,1)$, find the distribution of $X|Y = y$

And I was doing:

$f_{x|y}(x) \propto f_x(x)\cdot f_{Y|X=x}(y)$

$f_{x|y}(x) \propto exp(-\frac{(x-10)^2}{2}) \cdot exp(-\frac{(y-x)^2}{2})$

$f_{x|y}(x) \propto exp(-\frac{(x-10)^2 + (y-x)^2}{2})$

$f_{x|y}(x) \propto exp(-\frac{2x^2-20x-2xy+100+y^2}{2})$

$f_{x|y}(x) \propto exp(\frac{-2x^2+20x+2xy-100-y^2}{2})$

$f_{x|y}(x) \propto exp(\frac{-2x(x-10-y)}{2} - \frac{y^2+100}{2})$

How do I remove $x$ on the first term of the $exp(.)$, so I can have the new mean that I imagine would be $10+y$. Or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: I believe that you need to know the distribution of $Y$ for this.

Comment: If you complete the square you can drop all terms which don't depend on x as you're talking about proportionality. Then the resulting expression will be proportional to a normal pdf and you will be able to read off the mean and variance.

Comment: @DanPhillips you're right, I forgot to use that and it worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f_{x|y}(x) \propto exp(\frac{-1}{2}[2x^2-20x-2xy+100+y^2])$

just using the first 3 terms that depend on $x$

$2[x^2-(10+y)x]$

Completing squares

$2[ x^2-(y+10)x + (\frac{y+10}{2})^2 - (\frac{y+10}{2})^2]$

$2[(x-\frac{y+10}{2})^2 - (\frac{y+10}{2})^2]$

The initial expresion was

$exp(\frac{-1}{2}\cdot 2[(x-\frac{y+10}{2})^2 - (\frac{y+10}{2})^2])$

$exp(-[(x-\frac{y+10}{2})^2 - (\frac{y+10}{2})^2])$

$f_{x|y}(x) \propto exp(-(x-\frac{y+10}{2})^2)$

So the distribution is

$X|Y=y \sim N(\frac{y+10}{2},1/2)$